# c++ regex convert regex to c++ code

Tags: c++, regex, std

first time regex (in c++ that is)

I have a hard time writing

```
(?<=name=")(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*(?=")
```

that matches for example name="blabla" xyz as blabla as code...
How do I

```
std::regex  TheName("(?<=name=")(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*(?=")");
```

correctly please?

Comment: None of the regex flavors supported by C++ `std::regex` supports lookbehinds. Use a capturing group. `std::regex  TheName("name=\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capturing rather than positive lookbehind in C++ regex. Also, it is advisable to use the unroll-the-loop principle to unroll your `([^"\\]|\\.)*` subpattern to make the regex as fast as it can be, see `[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*`. Also, it is advisable to use raw string literals (see `R"(<PATTERN>)"`) when defining regex patterns in order to avoid overescaping.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/d33Zks):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string s = "name=\"bla \\\"bla\\\"\"";
    std::regex TheName(R"(name=\"([^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*)\")");
    std::smatch m;
    if (regex_search(s, m, TheName)) {
            std::cout << m[1].str() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result: `bla \"bla\"`

Comment: ok thx - I do have an issue.. I use gcc - it has the -std=c++11 flag set but the std::regex_search gives me invalid arguments - they seem fine to me. the example here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/ failes  to compile with the same error - do you have an idea?

Comment: Use the latest GCC version. What is yours?

Comment: gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0 I'm on windows atm

Comment: Maybe it does not support raw string literals? Try with `std::regex TheName("name=\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"");`

Comment: using gcc (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0  now - it compiles and runs fine now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ZoOl007 in your previous compiler you need to use "c++14" not "c++11" for raw string literals to work...

Comment: I tried that - it's very possible that what you say is correct - but I couldn't compile it with the c++14 flag